# Wordpress Twenty Fourteen: Changing color of the header

Tags: wordpress, colors, header

I am using Wordpress, theme Twenty Fourteen. I changed the color of the header with

**.site-header, .site:before {background-color: #ffffff;}**

The color of the header has changed as expected, but what happened is that the color of the left sidebar under the widgets changed as well. I don't know why....

Does anybody have idea why it happened and is there any solution?

Comment: Just find header.php,  add a unique class you want,  then modify that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of .site:before in you CSS. That is why your left nav is white. Just get familiar with inspecting your pages with the browser and you can figure this out easily.